# Standard way to store/upload application jar on Spark cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-submit

I have a Spark based Kubernetes cluster where I am using `spark-submit` to submit the jobs on cluster as needed.
e.g.

```
spark-submit \
    --master spark://my-spark-master-svc:7077 \
    --class com.Main \
    examples/jars/my-spark-application.jar
```

Here I have uploaded file `my-spark-application.jar` using `kubectl cp`  under the directory `examples/jars` on the master Pod/container before I run the `spark-submit` command.

Another option could be by mounting a Volume on the cluster and share the jar on the volume that way.

What is the typical way to share the application jar with the spark cluster while using `spark-submit` on Kubernetes?

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is a typical way, but it might be interesting to you to hear how I did it on a previous project. We used artifactory, which is a repository on which you can store any kind of artifacts (files, binaries, ...) that was used for many parts of the projects. We had a CICD pipeline that automatically shipped our jars on there. In our `spark-submit` command, we then simply referred to the URL of our artifactory like so: `http://artifactory-url:service-port/path-to-jar/jar-name.jar`.